# How to delete codes from bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket, commit

I've added a source code in a repository on bitbucket mistakenly
now i want to remove it.
can anyone tell me how to remove files from repository on bitbucket?

Answer (score 0):

Use `git-rm` to locally delete your file and then push the changes to your bitbucket repository.

Comment: when i commit a code i face this error"nothing to commit working directory clean error "

Comment: Please have a look at this blog post, describing how to remove deleted files. http://www.geekgumbo.com/2010/05/16/removing-deleted-files-from-your-git-working-directory/